# how to shift this priority queue?

Tags: priority-queue

My program is supposed to do 4 operations: `add`, `delete`, `show` and `exit` using a priority queue... here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
#define SIZE 5            /* Size of Queue */
int f=0,r=-1;       /* Global declarations */
typedef struct PRQ
{
     int ele;
     int pr;
     int sign;
}PriorityQ;
PriorityQ PQ[SIZE];

//***************************************************
void PQinsert(int elem, int pre)
{
     int i;       /* Function for Insert operation */
     if( r==SIZE-1) 
        printf("\n\n Overflow!!!!\n\n");
     else
     {
          i=r;
          ++r;
         while(PQ[i].pr >= pre && i >= 0) /* Find location for new elem */
         {
            PQ[i+1]=PQ[i];
            i--;
         }
         PQ[i+1].ele=elem;
         PQ[i+1].pr=pre;
     }
}
//***************************************************
PriorityQ PQdelete()
{                      /* Function for Delete operation */
    PriorityQ p;

    if(f > r) 
    {
         printf("\n\nUnderflow!!!!\n\n");
         p.ele=-1;p.pr=-1;
         return(p);
     }
     else
    {
        p=PQ[f];

        f=f+1;
        return(p);
     }
}
//***************************************************

void display()
{                  /* Function to display status of Queue */
     int i;
     if(r==SIZE-1) 
         printf(" \n Empty Queue\n");
    else
    {
     printf("Front->");
    for(i=f;i<=r;i++)
     printf("[%d,%d] ",PQ[i].ele,PQ[i].pr);
    printf("<-Rear");
    }
}

//***************************************************

int main()
{                         /* Main Program */
    int opn;
     PriorityQ p;
     do
     {
     system("cls");
     printf("\n ### Priority Queue Operations(DSC order) ### \n\n");
     printf("\n Press 1-Insert, 2-Delete,3-Display,4-Exit\n");
     printf("\n Your option ? ");
     scanf("%d",&opn);
    switch(opn)
    {
         case 1: 
             printf("\n\nRead the element and its Priority?");
             scanf("%d%d",&p.ele,&p.pr);
             PQinsert(p.ele,p.pr); break;
          case 2: 
              p=PQdelete();
              if( p.ele != -1)
              printf("\n\nDeleted Element is %d \n",p.ele);
              break;
          case 3: 
              printf("\n\nStatus of Queue\n\n");
                  display(); 
              break;
          case 4: 
              printf("\n\n Terminating \n\n"); 
              break;
          default: 
              printf("\n\nInvalid Option !!! Try Again !! \n\n");
                  break;
        }
        printf("\n\n\n\n  Press a Key to Continue . . . ");
        getch();
        }
     while(opn != 4);
}
```

Now I want to add a sign so that when an element is inserted the sign of that element in array,becomes 1 & when an element is deleted it's sign becomes 0... then I want to shift the homes that have the sign '1' to left, so that when an element is deleted from queue, the process of shifting will be done,in this way we won't have any empty space in the array and we can still add an element...

well this was all I wanted to do, but I tried different ways & I couldn't do what I wanted... Now I don't have any idea about what I should do!! :( would u please tell what should I do(how to add the sign and shift elements)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to understand why you need this sign marquing and the f indice.

What about modifying your delete function so it actually delete the element by shifting the queu and reducing the count r?

```
PriorityQ PQdelete()
{                      /* Function for Delete operation */
 PriorityQ p;
 int neshane;
 int loop_var;
 if(f > r)
 {
     printf("\n\nUnderflow!!!!\n\n");
     p.ele=-1;p.pr=-1;
     return(p);
 }
 else
 {
  p=PQ[0];
  // if one element: just reduce the count of element
  if(r==0)
   r--;
  else
  // if more than one: shift all elements to the left and reduce the count
  {
   for(loop_var=0; loop_var<r; loop_var++)
   {
    PQ[loop_var+1] = PQ[loop_var];
   }
   r--;
  }
  return(p);
 }
}
```

This should help you or maybe I didn't understood your question. Please let me know what you think about it.

Comment: tnx it was a good way,but the explanation that I gave about putting a sign and ... is the way that our professor has told us to do and is called logical remove !!! in logical remove,the sign of the homes that are empty will be 0 and the sign of the homes that are full will be 1, then we will search in queue to see whether the sign is 0 or 1, if we had 1 after a 0 we would push the home with the sign '1' to the left... so the home with '0' sign will be deleted & we won't have any empty place in the array !

Comment: Ok then: 
 when inserting change the value of sign to 1.
 when deleting change the value of sign of the element [f] to 0.
 add a cleaning function going through your list and replacing all
 0-marked element by the first one on its right. Then you will need to call this function at least every time you delete an element (or each turn of your loop).

Comment: yeah at first I did this, but I encountered a bug :( the function insert became an infinite loop, I mean I could insert elements without considering the defined amount: SIZE ! I guess my function was not correct or something. would u please help me with this function?

Comment: take your current function and add after "PQ[i+1].pr=pre;" the line "PQ[i+1].sign=1;". this would be enought if you use the cleaning function at least after all suppression of element.